# Jquery mobile, Footer does not move down with <data-position="fixed">

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I tried to put the footer down but it seems not to work with the code provided below.
 I also deleted all the standard text in the css file to ensure that there is no connection with my problem.. 
It should normally move down with

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h5>Test</h5>
</div>
```

right?

This is the complete code of my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link href="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <scrip src="js/jquery.js"type="text/javascript"></scrip>
        <script src="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
   <body>
    <div data-role="page" id ="home">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Your Resource App</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h5>Test</h5>
        </div>

    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
   </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's alright i forgot a t in here to write script xD